# Boot receiver without need to restart device

Tags: android

I have a receiver which fires when boot is completes, using inter filter `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.
The problem is, when the user installs the app, i want this event to be fired. Without the user having to reboot the device. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.  In fact, the user must start your app manually at least 1 time before `BOOT_COMPLETED` will ever get delivered to your app.  This is done by the framework to prevent apps from installing things which sit in the background without the user's knowledge.

Comment: Isn't there a way to fire the code i have in the `onReceive` method when i launch my app for the first time? and check if the receiver was already fired the second time the user restarts the device after opening the app (to avoid firing the same method twice)?

Comment: You would have to manage that yourself using some type of common code and making a record of the fact that your 1 time execution code has been executed.  Something like a `SharedPreference` would probably do the job.